# How do I pass a variable from one Class to another in Android

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

How do I assign user input (from a TextView) into a variable then call that variable in another class?

From my MainActivity, I have the followingn where user input is taken:

```
Button confirm;
EditText inputField;
String typedChar;
char[] cars = typedChar.toCharArray();

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    confirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btConfirmInput);

    inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInputChars);

    confirm.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  typedChar = inputField.getText().toString();

                }
            }
    );
```

I'm trying to store the input and convert it to char

```
String typedChar;
    char[] cars = typedChar.toCharArray();
```

Now I want to use `cars` in another class in the following method which print to a custom view:

```
 private void drawText() {
        for (int i = 0; i < txtPosByColumn.length; i++) {
            canvas.drawText("" + cars[RANDOM.nextInt(cars.length)], i * fontSize, txtPosByColumn[i] * fontSize, paintTxt);

            if (txtPosByColumn[i] * fontSize > height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
                txtPosByColumn[i] = 0;
            }

            txtPosByColumn[i]++;
        }
```

I'm however able to assign hardcoded value to `cars` like bellow:

```
private char[] chars = "010101".toCharArray();
```

but I want it come from user input

Anyone please kindly advice, guide. I know I'm doing things wrong but can't figure out...

PS: Noob here

Comment: Is the `AnotherClass` an Activity??

Comment: The calss is a custom view that extends View

Comment: `char[] cars = typedChar.toCharArray();` is going to get executed on init of your class and not do anything.

Comment: Then make constructor in that class that accepts a char array or String...

Comment: Okay xenolin, how? I'm a bit new to almost everything :D

Comment: What do you mean @rguessford

Comment: Wish I could DM you, SO is frustrating in that regard. You need to know more about Java and program flow.

Comment: You're right... @rguessford

Answer (score 1):

You put your variable in an Intent like this:

```
confirm.setOnClickListener(
     new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typedChar = inputField.getText().toString();
            char[] chars = typedChar.toCharArray();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, MySecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("somethingWithARelevantName", chars);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
       }
    );
```

And you get it in your second activity like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
char[] chars = intent.getExtras().getCharArray("somethingWithARelevantName");
```

edit: if want your variable in a class that is not an activity, you can pass it in the constructor:

```
class MyClass{

    char[] chars;

    MyClass(char[] chars){

        this.chars = chars;

    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should the first code goes, in the MainActivtyN then use the second code in the other class?

Comment: But here the value of chars is hardcoded, I want it set by user input instead

Comment: You can put the first part in your button's listener, and the second on the method onCreated in your second activity. I edited my answer.

Comment: Okay, see that. BUt the other class is simply a custom view. I found the solution already. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should specified what is the type of that other class.
If it is a simple Java class you can pass it as a field to your drawText(char[] array);
If however you are dealing with activities the : 
In your first activity, before launching the other activity, use Extra intent to send data between activities as the answer show before.